# Rails Routing Continue on Fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to see if there is a way in rails routing to 'return' from the controller when a route doesn't match to continue down the routes.rb without using constraints.

My Goal is to make these routes work without constraints:

```
match ":postname" => "post#show"
match ":pagename" => "page#show"
```

For arguments sake, posts and pages have different controllers. Is it possible to:

- If there are no posts for the post controller to retrieve, gracefully fail, then  continue routing onto the page controller?

I ask this because using :constraints => Post.new will use a DB query to check. This runs 2 DB queries to get to the data: Once when seeing if there is a valid route and second when we go to retrieve the data in the controller.

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: Bad practice!, Please talk about your business logic/need we will find out the right practice.

Comment: @beck03076 Thanks for the fast reply! I believe the business logic is I want 2 controllers to handle routes that overlap the same /<pagename-url>/ area. They perform drastically different functions so adding them to one controller doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [Rails Caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) as a 'global' variable reading it back out in the controller so I don't double dip to the DB.